# trigger for before delete a record

Tags: sql-server-2005

I'm using sql server 2005 and have 2 tables in my database.
How can I write a trigger that can INSERT a record into table 2 BEFORE delete in table 1? 
How can I do this?
I need this for VB.Net.
I've already done a connection with Sql server.

Comment: Please post the trigger code you have written so far. People generally do not like to just write your code for you.

Comment: thank u.......next time i remember.........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logically, whether the INSERT is before or after the DELETE does not matter because the trigger is part of the implicit transaction created by the DELETE.

So if the INSERT fails, the DELETE is rolled back (with appropriate handling). INSERT first, them DELETE would the same.

In other words, you can use INSTEAD OF (or BEFORE) triggers to do the INSERT but you then have to write your own DELETE in the trigger. Because of what I said above about transactions, you can use an AFTER/FOR trigger. Something like Pankaj Agarwal's answer

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there are two table tblA and tblB.
when any record delete from tblA then using trigger we can insert that deleted record into tblB

```
create trigger t1 on tblA 
for delete
as
insert into tblB select * from deleted
```